# Error: Invalid argument to useRecoilState: expected an atom or selector but got undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, recoiljs

I got this error but I have no idea why I got this error. I did everything fine. I am using useRecoilState in Next JS to manage my state.

[image: Error Image]

Here's the link to repo: https://github.com/dingus45191/Radiant-Covid-Emergency-Site

**Works now just remove any unnecessary recoil imports**

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your project, build it, ran it with npm start, the app loads fine. See below,

[image]

I do get an error in the console, but I believe that is irrevalent with your error. See below.
[image]